# ^m removing sed command removing ,M data as well

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am using this code:

```
sed -E ':a;N;;s/(,"[^"]*)\n/\1/;$!ba' $target > Int.csv
#sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' $target > Int.csv
sed -e "s/\r//g" Int.csv > Removejunk.csv
```

My requirement is to remove the `\n` character from the csv file and also remove the `^m` character.

But in the output, `M` is also getting removed.

I.e i get `10-01-2020 08:16 AM,ichael Flores`
instead of `10-01-2020 08:16 AM,Michael Flores`

Comment: Please add unambiguous sample input and expected output.

Comment: Yes. We can't help you parse text that you do not show us. We need to see what the input to the commands is and also what your expected output is.

Comment: And it may be useful to also show the output of your sample input piped through `od -An -c` (or `od -An -c -tx1`) to also make non-printable characters visible.

Comment: sample data

09-14-2020 05:45 PM,sohini, Hi how are 
you i am fine , sample

i am expecting

09-14-2020 05:45 PM,Mohini, Hi how are you i am fine , sample

what i am getting now

09-14-2020 05:45 P,sohini, Hi how are 
you i am fine , ^Msample

above sed command which i mentioned in question replacing the ,M or M, in the data instead of ^M

Comment: Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/613858/edit) your question instead of adding information in comments; they are not meant to stay and the lack of formatting makes them quite hard to read (especially because newlines are lost). Also, are there any carriage returns (`^M`) in your sample data? If yes, in which position are they?